# Error "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast array = NULL"

Tags: c, pointers, null, malloc

When I compile my project I get the error ("assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast array = NULL"). I don't understand why it works in the if statement and not in the else statement.

```
    FILE *fp;
int i,j,m,n;
char citemp;

if (!(fp = fopen(trainingsInputFile, "r"))) {
    perror("Datei konnte nicht gelesen werden");
}
else {
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    n = 0;
    char *carray = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    while (!feof(fp)) {            
        citemp = getc(fp);

        if(citemp != ';'){                
            if(citemp != ','){ 
                carray[j] = citemp;
                j++;                       
            }else{                    
                trainingsInputArray[n][i] = atof(carray);
                for(m = 0; m < j; m++){
                    carray[m] = NULL;
                }
                j = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }else{
            n++;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

Error:
environment.c:21: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
                         carray[m] = NULL;

Comment: `while(!feof(fp))` is always wrong.

Comment: Could you please create a minimal, complete and verifiable example?

Comment: please edit to also include in which line the error appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is the line `carray[m] = NULL`. NULL seems to be defined as `((void*)0)`, not just `0`, so the compiler has correctly recognized that you are assigning a pointer (`NULL`) to an integer value (`carray[m]`) which is a `char`. Change the line to `carray[m] = 0` instead and that particular error should go away.

Comment: @pepe You're welcome, glad to help - feel free to accept my answer then :)